# autoIT resizable terminal service

Tags: terminal, resize, autoit, resizable

When I resize "Terminal server", I want that the "RDP session" follow the resizing without grey borders appear

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

I have the following code:

```
$host = "" ;<<<<<<< enter here the host name or ip address 
$hGUI = GUICreate("Terminal server", 900, 700, -1, -1, BitOR($GUI_SS_DEFAULT_GUI,$WS_SIZEBOX,$WS_THICKFRAME))
$oRDP = ObjCreate("MsTscAx.MsTscAx.2")
$oRDP_Ctrl = GUICtrlCreateObj($oRDP, 0, 0, 900, 700)
GUICtrlSetResizing(-1,GUI_DOCKLEFT+$GUI_DOCKRIGHT+$GUI_DOCKTOP+$GUI_DOCKBOTTOM+$GUI_DOCKWID    TH+$GUI_DOCKHEIGHT) GUICtrlSetStyle($oRDP_Ctrl , $WS_VISIBLE)
$oRDP.DesktopWidth = 900
$oRDP.DesktopHeight = 700
$oRDP.Fullscreen = False
$oRDP.ColorDepth = 16
$oRDP.AdvancedSettings3.SmartSizing = True
$oRDP.Server = $host
$oRDP.UserName = "" ;<<<<<<< enter here the user name 
$oRDP.Domain = "" 
$oRDP.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = ""
$oRDP.ConnectingText = "Connecting to " & $host
$oRDP.DisconnectedText = "Disconnected from " & $host
$oRDP.StartConnected = True
$oRDP.Connect()
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hGUI)
$oShel = ObjCreate("shell.application")
$oShel_Ctrl = GUICtrlCreateObj($oShel, 0, 0, 900, 700) 
GUICtrlSetStyle($oShel_Ctrl , $WS_VISIBLE)

Send("#r")
Send ("C:\Program Files (x86)\scripts\PSTools\******.bat")
Send("{ENTER}") 

While 1    
 $nMsg = GUIGetMsg() 
 Switch $nMsg       
   Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE 
     $oRDP.Disconnect() 
     Exit 
 EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. The code example is full of small errors and does not illustrate the problem. When I resize the window it works just fine. What is it that you want exactly?

Comment: I don't want the borders when I resize and I don't know how can I do..

Answer (score 0):

You really only need:

`$hGUI = GUICreate("Terminal server", 900, 700, -1, -1, $WS_POPUP)`

If you are trying to make it so there is absolutely NO borders, then the `$WS_POPUP` is what you want to use, exactly as above. It's very hard to understand your broken english, my apologies.

Comment: The only way you can make this resizable is by putting `$WS_POPUP + $WS_SIZEBOX` in the styles parameter. Yet, this will always give it a border. The border will not include the Exit, Maximize, and Minimize buttons though (because of $WS_POPUP).

Comment: I want that the session opened in the "Terminal server" follow the resizing without some grey borders which appear

Comment: That's exactly what I have shown you above. Using the $WS_POPUP will take away all borders. If you want to resize the window though, you MUST have borders with $WS_SIZEBOX. You will NOT be able to resize without borders.

Comment: If you're trying to make something inside the GUI window resizable just do this: `GUISetResizing($ControlID, $GUI_DOCKAUTO)`

Comment: Resize is ok but, WHEN I resize the borders appear.. and I don't know why

Comment: I've never seen a border not there and then reappear when resizing, but that could because you haven't specified which border you are trying to resize, I'm just going off your exceptionally hard to understand English. `GUISetResizing($oRDP_Ctrl, $GUI_DOCKAUTO)` hopefully this is what you want. I doubt many people are going to want to jump in and help, I would brush up on some small grammar points to help with understanting when asking questions. :)